# classical AI, ontology, machine learning, bayesian

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, bayesian

I'm starting to study machine learning and bayesian inference applied to computer vision and affective computing.

If I understand right, there is a big discussion between

- classical IA, ontology, semantic web researchers
- and machine learning and bayesian guys

I think it is usually referred as strong AI vs weak AI related also to philosophical issues like functional psychology (brain as black box set) and cognitive psychology (theory of mind, mirror neuron), but this is not the point in a programming forum like this.

I'd like to understand the differences between the two points of view. Ideally, answers will reference examples and academic papers where one approach get good results and the other fails. I am also interested in the historical trends: why approaches fell out of favour and a newer approaches began to rise up. For example, I know that Bayesian inference is computationally intractable, problem in NP, and that's why for a long time probabilistic models was not favoured in information technology world. However, they've began to rise up in econometrics.

Comment: So, did you get the fields for title and tags confused?

Answer (score 4):

I think you have got several ideas mixed up together. It's true that there is a distinction that gets drawn between rule-based and probabilistic approaches to 'AI' tasks, however it has nothing to do with strong or weak AI, very little to do with psychology and it's not nearly as clear cut as being a battle between two opposing sides. Also, I think saying Bayesian inference was not used in computer science because inference is NP complete in general is a bit misleading. That result often doesn't matter that much in practice and most machine learning algorithms don't do real Bayesian inference anyway.

Having said all that, the history of Natural Language Processing went from rule-based systems in the 80s and early 90s to machine learning systems up to the present day. Look at the history of the [MUC conferences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Understanding_Conference) to see the early approaches to information extraction task. Compare that with the current state-of-the-art in named entity recognition and parsing (the [ACL wiki](http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=State_of_the_art) is a good source for this) which are all based on machine learning methods.

As far as specific references, I doubt you'll find anyone writing an academic paper that says 'statistical systems are better than rule-based systems' because it's often very hard to make a definite statement like that. A quick Google for 'statistical vs. rule based' yields papers like [this](http://www.mt-archive.info/LREC-2004-Thurmair-2.pdf) which looks at machine translation and recommends using both approaches, according to their strengths and weaknesses. I think you'll find that this is pretty typical of academic papers. The only thing I've read that really makes a stand on the issue is '[The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Data](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/35179.pdf)' which is a good read.

Answer (score 3):

As for the "rule-based" vs. " probabilistic" thing you can go for the classic book by Judea Pearl - "Probabilistic Reasoning in Intelligent Systems. Pearl writes very biased towards what he calls "intensional systems" which is basically the counter-part to rule-based stuff. I think this book is what set off the whole probabilistic thing in AI (you can also argue the time was due, but then it was THE book of that time).

I think machine-learning is a different story (though it's nearer to probabilistic AI than to logics).